# How can I set up an Access VBA library

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have some VBA code that I use across multiple projects - about 40 or so different data bases all use many of the same functions.

I try to use the same code in application each for consistency.  Is there a way I can put all the code in one library and make it available to each data base?  I'm getting tired of copying the code to a new data base every time I want to re-use it.  I'm especially getting tired of maintaining it in multiple places when I want to change the functions.

I have the same question for Excel - can I create an Excel library and include it in all my workbooks?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194944(v=office.15).aspx but it is probably not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the VBA code works in VB6, you could create a DLL using VB6. The DLL would be a library of methods you could use across board just by referencing the DLL.

If it does not, you should create an Ms Access MDA file (add-in file) for all your reusable code, that can be added into any Access (or probably Excel) project.

Comment: Thanks.  In researching MDA files, I found how to add them with vba using Application.References.AddFromFile - exactly what I need.  And I can add from a .accdb file directly, so I don't even need the MDA file.

Answer (score -1):

Create one or many excel's per project, save those as *.xla. (Excel Add-In)

Go to your Excel Options and configure to load automatically those add-ins or thru VBA in your workbooks.

[image: Walkthru]

Using VBA Automation:

```
Application.AddIns.Add(XLA_Path)
```